# my <scprit> doesn't load my js file & my browser cant load it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use `<script>` to link my javascript file to my html,
but it doesn't recognize any of my code. I'm doing exactly as the tutorials said, and it's working fine in the tutorials. When I open my '.html' file it can't load the js file. Not even a simple alert!

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="text.js">    
    var rang = document.getElementById("rang")
    rang.onclick = function () {
        rang.style.backgroundColor="Red"     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: You either ahve a src set on your script or you have the script directly inside the script tags. don't mix it like in your example.